# Upload Image to Canvas p5js

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I am a beginner at p5js, and I was learning how to upload an image. This is my code:

```js
PImage img;

function setup() {
  size(1400, 1400)
  img = loadImage("india-map.gif");
}


function draw() {
  background(0)
  image(img, 100, 100);
}
```

When I run it, it says that there is a problem with line 1. The error message reads:

> SyntaxError: Expected ;but found img.

I don't know what this means and what I should do. Can anyone help me?

Edit:

I changed the code to

```js
var image1;


function preload(){
 image1= loadImage("india-map.jpg");
}

function setup(){
  
 creatCanvas(1350,600) 
}

function draw(){
image(image1, 100, 100); 
  
}
```

My page just says ...loading without loading any image.

Comment: You're mixing up P5js (Javascript) and Processing3 (Java). There are no types (hint: PImage) in javascript. Replace PImage with let.

Comment: Regarding your edit: please ask new questions in their own posts, and make sure you're looking in your [developer tools](https://happycoding.io/tutorials/javascript/developer-tools) for JavaScript errors.

Comment: @BobTimmon After your edit, you have a typo: `creatCanvas`, which should be `createCanvas`. Did you check your console for errors? After fixing that, making sure you're running on a server so your image can be loaded from the file system, it should work, as [Nick's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54719421/6243352) describes.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to kemicofa great answer, I think it is also important to note the `loadImage` is asynchronous. This means that when we call `loadImage` it will take some time for the method to retrieve and load the image data into memory. As a result of this, `loadImage` doesn't happen instantly like the rest of your code.

Thus, while your image is being loaded, the rest of your code is still able to run, including the `draw` method. This means that if your draw method only runs once (you can make it run only once by using `noLoop()`, your image will not be displayed because it hasn't yet been loaded in.

There are a couple of solutions to this issue such as using a *callback*. However, p5js offers another method which runs before `setup` called `preload`. In this function, you can load your image to make sure that it is ready for `setup` and `draw` to use.

Using all these ideas you will end up with code which looks somewhat like:

```
let img;

function preload() {
  img = loadImage('india-map.gif'); // load media and other data
}

function setup() { // only executed once preload is has finished loading data
  createCanvas(400, 400);

}

function draw() { // only executed once preload is has finished loading data
  image(img, 0, 0, width, height);
  noLoop(); // stop draw from looping (to show img has been loaded)
}
```

You can find a working example [here](https://editor.p5js.org/NickParsons/sketches/pWaG8_ZZ_)

Answer (score 0):

### Explanation:

[`PImage`](https://processing.org/reference/image_.html) is a type coming from the Processing3 library.

In javascript, when declaring a variable use `const`, `let` or `var`.

Additionally, the `size` method comes from Processing3 as well. Instead use [`createCanvas`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/createCanvas) method and pass the size as a parameter.

Go over the [documentation](https://p5js.org/reference/]) and make sure the methods you wish to use exist.

### Solution:

```
let img;
function setup() {
  createCanvas(100, 50);
  img = loadImage("india-map.gif");
}


function draw() {
  background(0);
  image(img, 100, 100);
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. If you add `noLoop()` to the end of the `draw` function, you'll see that P5.js isn't awaiting the async image load fired by `loadImage`, so you'll get a blank screen. The solution is to use p5's `preload` function to load images rather than `setup`, as described in [Nick's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54719421/6243352), so that p5 correctly awaits all of the data before running `setup` and `draw` (p5 shows "Loading..." on the screen when this is happening). Then, it's possible to use `noLoop()` in `draw` and draw the image in a single rendering step.