# How can I draw over an animated gif created with createImg in p5.js?

Tags: p5.js

My code is along the line of that:

```
function setup(){
   createCanvas(400,400);
   pg = createGraphics(400,400);
   gif_createImg = createImg("my.gif");
    
}

function draw(){
    pg.clear();
    show(x,y,d);
    pg.strokeWeight(2*d);
    pg.point(x,y);
    image(pg,0,0);
}

function show(x,y,d) {
    gif_createImg.size(d,d);
    gif_createImg.position(x,y);
}
```

The point draws below my gif, why? I'm stating it below the gif. And how can I get it to draw above the gif?

I tried it with createGraphics and it did not work (though it's the first time I've ever used that).

I understand that createImg creates an Element which acts different than things like points or images (e.g it does not change with transform() etc.). I searched for that but couldn't find a good explantation or references on how to deal with Elements.

Comment: The `<img>` element is on top of the canvas, so the drawing order is ignored. Draw the image onto the canvas: https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/image. Otherwise, you could make the canvas transparent and put its z-index on top of the gif, but that's probably more work. "I tried it with createGraphics and it did not work" -- it's important to show these attempts so they can be debugged.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Upload Image to Canvas p5js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54710728/upload-image-to-canvas-p5js)

Comment: See also [Drawing to p5.Image instead of to canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39393502/drawing-to-p5-image-instead-of-to-canvas)

Comment: I edited it to show the attempt with createGraphics (should I have left the other one?). Image won't work, as than the gif won't animate and I've already tried to put an image above the gif but it's acting in the same manner as the point. The second link also deals with loadImage() which won't work. Did I understand that correctly that createImg() creates an HTML element that is not in the canvas? So is there even a way to overlay this element with the canvas?

Comment: Thanks. I didn't realize we were working with an animated gif. I'd try the second suggestion of using `createImg`, then positioning a transparent canvas on top of the `<img>` using z-index for handling the drawing overlay. As an alternative to that, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49650025/p5-js-animated-gif-doesnt-work) which suggests p5.gif.js which I haven't used before.

Comment: p5.gif.js works perfectly, thanks. But out of interest: I couldn't find anything on how to change the z-index. Do you know somewhere where that is explained?

Comment: If you use p5.gif.js, I assume z-index doesn't apply since it's all-canvas. See [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index) for z-index information. If you worked something out, can you post a [self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) to help future visitors with the same problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So, to draw over an animated gif one can use [p5.gif.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49650025/p5-js-animated-gif-doesnt-work), works flawlessly.

The point "2.Use dependency" in the answer of the listed thread should explain everything.

Though there you don't use an `<img>` element (you create an animated p5.Image).

The code gets reduced to that:

```
function setup(){
   gif = loadGif('my.gif');
    
}

function draw(){
    image(gif,0,0);
}
```

Thanks to [ggorlen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6243352/ggorlen), you saved my week ':)

Comment: Thanks--could you post your solution code?